# How do I prove this by mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$\frac{1}{2}+  \frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}  = 1 -  \frac{1}{2^n}$$
I can do induction but I'm really struggling on this one in the proof part. It's the fractions and exponents that are throwing me off.
[Induction problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0IcV.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Hi, please type out the math in the question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Don't post pictures and show us your work or explain where you are stuck.

Comment: For induction: [1] How much is $\displaystyle \left[1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right] + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$? and [2] What is the relevance of the question that I posed in [1]?

Comment: Hi, sorry everyone for not knowing the regs on pictures etc. So I work through my base case, then assume p(k) is true and then try to prove p(k+1). So my work looks like this:

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to write a clear induction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof)

Comment: my work looks like this when I start the proof:
Hi, sorry everyone for not knowing the regs on pictures etc. So I work through my base case, then assume p(k) is true and then try to prove p(k+1). So my work as I start the proof looks like this:
1 - \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^k+1)}
I then am struggling to work out how to simplify that to my end goal of 1- \frac{1}{2^k+1}

Comment: I'm struggling to learn mathjax sorry

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of consecutive terms in a geometric sequence?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the induction proof guide. I don't think it's the induction process that's stumping me. It's the actual algebra involved. I'm sorry but I've come late to maths and am trying to learn as I go. I'm not sure what 1 - 1/2^n would be, it depends on n and I don't know how to vocalise it. If n = 2 it'd be 3/4. This is what's confusing me. I'm always left with something on top of the 1/2^n+1 that I need and I can't see how to get rid of it.

Comment: sn = a1(1-r^n)/1-r

Comment: *Hint*: If you absolutely have to use induction: $\;\dfrac1{2^n}=\dfrac 2{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show using mathematical induction that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141126/how-can-i-show-using-mathematical-induction-that-frac12-frac14-c)

Comment: "I'm not sure what 1 - 1/2^n would be"  It doesn't matter but it would be $\frac {2^n -1}{2^n}$.  You can do the induction either by noting $(1-\frac 1{2^n}) + \frac 1{2^{n+1}} = 1 +(\frac 1{2^{n+1}} - \frac 1{2^n}) = 1-\frac 1{2^{n+1}}$ or by noting that $(1-\frac 1{2^n})+\frac 1{2^{n+1}} = \frac {2^n -1}{2^n} + \frac 1{2^{n+1}}= \frac {2^{n+1}-2}{2^{n+1}} + \frac 1{2^{n+1}} = \frac {2^{n+1} -1}{2^{n+1}} = 1 - \frac 1{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: "Do you know the formula for the sum of consecutive terms in a geometric sequence?"  Not useful as that is *exactly* what is being asked to be proven.

Comment: " 1 - \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^k+1)} I then am struggling to work out how to simplify that to my end goal of 1- \frac{1}{2^k+1} "  $$1 -\frac 1{2^k} +\frac 1{2^{k+1}} = 1+(\frac 1{2^{k+1}} - \frac 1{2^k}) = 1 + (\frac 1{2^{k+1}} - \frac 1{2^k}\cdot \frac 22) = 1+(\frac 1{2^{k+1}} - \frac 2{2^{k+1}}) =1+(\frac {1-2}{2^{k+1}}) = 1 + (\frac{-1}{2^{k+1}}) = 1 - \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$$

Comment: .. or in other words.... put $-\frac 1{2^n}$ and $\frac 1{2^{k+1}}$ over a common denominator and combine.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious for $n=1$, so suppose its true for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e., $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$ We have $$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
&=1-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{2}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=1+\frac{1-2}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\end{align*}$$
which completes the induction.