# How to prove by induction $\frac 12 + \frac 14 + ... + \frac {1}{2^n} = 1- \frac {1}{2^n} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I'm trying to solve this problem about mathematical induction but every time I try to solve it I end up with an incorrect answer.
The problem is as follows:

Prove by induction : $$\frac 12 + \frac 14 + ... + \frac {1}{2^n} = 1- \frac {1}{2^n} $$

my work:
first I prove that it holds for n=1: $\frac 12 = 1- \frac {1}{2^1} = \frac 12$

Now assume it holds for n=k, prove for n=k+1 the sum is equal to $1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$

then $\frac 12 + \frac 14 +...+ \frac {1}{2^k} + \frac {1}{2^{k+1}} = 1-\frac {1}{2^k} + \frac {1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac {2^{k+1}+2^k}{2^{k+1}2^k} = 1- \frac {2(2^k)+2^k}{2(2^k)2^k} = 1 - \frac {3(2^k)}{2(2^k)2^k} = 1- \frac {3}{2(2^k)} = 1- \frac {3}{2^{k+1}}  $

I would very much appreciate if at least someone can tell me where I'm wrong so I could try to solve it by myself. I think the mistake is at factoring $2^{k+1}+2^k$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove this by mathematical induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172800/how-do-i-prove-this-by-mathematical-induction). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%20%2B%20%5Cldots%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%20%3D%201%20-%20%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI, adding $1$ to both sides, we then also have  [Prove by mathematical induction for all n in N](/q/1282152), [Mathematical Induction with Exponents: $1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac1{2^{n}} = 2 - \frac1{2^{n}}$](/q/2060530) and [What am I doing wrong in this induction question?](/q/2834711).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with the minus sign.
$$-\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{-2^{k+1} + 2^k}{2^k 2^{k+1}}
= \frac{-2 + 1}{2^{k+1}} = -\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't see that mistake

Answer (score 4):

You went wrong when you combined the fractions. You should have $$1- \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{2^{k+1} - 2^k}{2^{k+1}2^k} = 1 - \frac{2 - 1}{2^{k+1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$

Comment: how could i have missed that?!!! thank you for your answer